# Get value of property in dll

Tags: c#, dll, properties

I have project that using object from dll.

```
namespace XXX.XXX.XXX.Nsi
{
    [Serializable]
    [DataContract]
    [MayBeAmplified]
    public class GngInfo
    {
        public GngInfo();
        [MaxLenValidator(1000)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I need to find where `Name` get specific value for example "Cargo".
What ways exist to do this?

1. Modify huge dll and replace it. But I do not have source code of dll.
2. Rewrite all places where used `GngInfo` with another object implemented not in dll.

What other ways?

Comment: You can  use Aspects like Castle.DynamicProxy to  intercept property.Look  at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959812/intercept-properties-with-castle-windsor-iinterceptor for example

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `class` `MyGngInfo` which inherits from `GngInfo` and implement your custom logic. When you are done, replace `GngInfo` usages with `MyGngInfo` usages.